# Is there a way to sync different directories to different branches in the same project/repo in Git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have two version of a website that I ideally would like to sync with an existing Git repo. They are in two different physical directories on my local machine.

Is there a way I can add the contents of one folder to one branch and the other to a different branch?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, set up a git repository in both directories with `git init`. Then, create a different branch in each directory with `git checkout -b branch-name`. Put whatever filespecs you wish into `.gitignore` in both directories, then `git add` the appropriate files in each directory. Finally, add the **same** remote in both directories with `git remote`. `git push` them both, and you will have a single repository with two branches, with two local directories, one mapped to each branch.

Note that the first time you try merging these branches, you will get a lot of conflicts. That is because there is no base branch which these two branches sprung from, so git will have no idea of knowing which version of a file should be the "real" one.